# Semi join sub-selects are not allowed with the 'OR' operator

Tags: soql

This error is killing me :(

**Semi join sub-selects are only allowed at the top level WHERE expressions and not in nested WHERE expressions**

(or)

**Semi join sub-selects are not allowed with the 'OR' operator**

Here is my code. Can someone help?

Note :- I can't convert the select query that I have written in my where clause to a seperate query (Where Id in (select.... ) and get the data in an id set and substitute in the below query, because my id set has about 35000 records and when I try to query with that set it throws a Time limit exceeded error as it is unable to handle even more than a 1000 or 2000 records in a set if it is in an SOQL IN clause.

And I have just given a sample code here by getting the count, I need to get the count as well as the actual data..

```
Id CompanyId = '001Z000000CF2PtIAL';
 String SearchText = '%test%';
 Set<Id> SearchgroupassetidSet = new Set<ID>();
 SearchgroupassetidSet.add('a7aZ00000004CHhIAM');
 SearchgroupassetidSet.add('a7aZ00000004CHiIAM');
 SearchgroupassetidSet.add('a7aZ00000004CHjIAM');
 SearchgroupassetidSet.add('a7aZ00000004CHkIAM');
 Integer RecCount=0;
  List<AggregateResult> lstaggResult = [Select count(id) RecCount  FROM Asset__c where  Id IN (Select Asset__c from Customer_Asset__c where isDeleted =false and Company__c =: CompanyId and (Asset__r.Title__c like : SearchText or Asset__r.Name like : SearchText)) 
 or (Group__c IN : SearchgroupassetidSet and ((Title__c like : SearchText) or (Name like : SearchText)))];

  if (lstaggResult.size() > 0)
    {
        RecCount = (Integer)lstaggResult[0].get('RecCount');                        
    }
    System.debug('Record Count : ' + RecCount);
```

Answer (score 4):

As you state, normally you need to do the subquery separately and store the IDs in a set you can then use in the main query:

```
set<Id> AssetSet = new set<Id>();

for(Customer_Asset__c asset : [Select Asset__c from Customer_Asset__c where isDeleted = false and Company__c =: CompanyId and (Asset__r.Title__c like : SearchText or Asset__r.Name like : SearchText)])
{
  AssetSet.add(asset.Asset__c);
} 

List<AggregateResult> lstaggResult = [Select count(id) RecCount  FROM Asset__c where  Id IN 
: AssetSet or (Group__c IN : SearchgroupassetidSet and ((Title__c like : SearchText) or (Name like : SearchText)))];
```

However, if you're sure you can't do this then it would suggest that you may need to use **batch apex** to do the first (sub) query, leveraging `database.Stateful` to help with managing the data.

Alternatively look for a way to leverage other fields to reduce the scope of the query.

**Important note**

In your code you've got a lot of hard coded IDs, e.g. `Id CompanyId = '001Z000000CF2PtIAL';` and `SearchgroupassetidSet.add('a7aZ00000004CHhIAM');`

You should be aware that this is considered bad practice, because once you try to move this code to a different org, say a production environment, these IDs will no longer be valid and as such your code will fail to run.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your answer. I know that I have hard coded :) I have already mentioned that in my question itself.. this is just a test code.. I used another query to populate that set..

The problem is that i need to pull the data out from this query in to a list and add it to a List<Wrapperclass> type and bind it to a jqgrid in VF Page. so unfortunately i cant use batch apex here :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure of what your main goal is, but it seems to be generating some kind of analysis view of the data in question. I would use a batch to roll up my numbers into a custom object and then just display the latest info on the visualforce page. You could schedule the batch to keep it reasonably up to date, and even provide a button for users to kick it off manually if need be.

Comment: Actually I have to show some asset data that is stored in object and whatever has been assigned for each customer i need to show that in a jqgrid in visualforce page in sites

Answer (score 0):

1. apex:page's readOnly="true" probably won't help you.
2. All the LIKE look as if they are the reason of timeouts, not only the size of Set of Ids.. A SOSL query might be better in your case and you can still use [WHERE clauses in it](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm#conditionExp) to further filter down the results. The question is whether you're fine with displaying "over 200 results" on your Site or does it have to be 100% accurate?
3. Maybe some kind of Analytic Snapshot can save you. Either a real one (based on a scheduled report) or code solution. Batch job or trigger (even with @future) to recalculate some total and insert aggregated helper data somewhere?
4. Bit more hardcore - try to apply small limit on it (say LIMIT 10) and if it works - consider using a standardSetController, queryMore(), maybe even paginated solution?